# How replace url product in shopify

Tags: seo, shopify

It is possible to do such that url product in shopify instead of ?variant replace with seo friendly path.
what I mean: there are 2 t-shirts blue and white. in shopify, they are displayed as
https://site/collections/tshirts/products/brand?variant=01234567891 as blue
https://site/collections/tshirts/products/brand?variant=01234567892 as white,

and I need to https://site/collections/tshirts/products/brand/blue
https://site/collections/tshirts/products/brand/white

Answer (score 0):

Shopify has a fixed URL structure that can't be modified.

This means that you **can't** rewrite the URL in any way or form outside the supported standards and the described URL from your question is not supported.

The only way to achieve somewhat this URL is to use the 301 redirects page in Shopify to redirect the URL you want to their Shopify equivalent.

Comment: I set up a redirect, but it only works with /products/brand/blue on /products/brand?variant=01234567891 and I need the opposite with  /products/brand?variant=01234567891 on /products/brand/blue

Comment: @lexx633 You can't you must redirect to the Shopify URL not the other way around.